# Could not be set to a Double value, non-null value of type Single

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have one problem which I try to find but I still not find the way to fix it. When I run the program the message throw like below

The 'fldscr1' property on 'tblssscr' could not be set to a 'Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Single'.

Here is my class to run my project:

```
public class tblssscr
{
    [Key]
    public int tblssscrId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Request code")]
    public int fldssrid { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("StudentId")]
    public int tblss_studentId { get; set; }
    public virtual tblss_student tblss_student { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Student Tempcode")]
    public string fldstdtmpcode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Attandence")]
    public int fldatt { get; set; }   

    [DisplayName("Discount (%)")]
    public int flddiscount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Score 1 is required!")]
    [DisplayName("Score 1")]       
    public float? fldscr1 { get; set; }   

    [DisplayName("Score 2")]       
    public float fldscr2 { get; set; }    

    [DisplayName("Total Score")]       
    public float fldtscr { get; set; }    

    [DisplayName("Offer Code")]
    public int fldrst { get; set; }              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store a double in `fldscr1` set it to a double like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Score 1 is required!")]
[DisplayName("Score 1")]   
public double fldscr1 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
[DisplayName("Score 1")]       
public float? fldscr1 { get; set; }
```

To:

```
[DisplayName("Score 1")]       
public float fldscr1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: I noticed that, too, but isn't that probably a typo when transcribing to SO?

Comment: you can easly assign float to double. Double a = new float();

Comment: Right, but not the other way.  The error is saying he was trying to store a double in a float.

Comment: Hmm, you are right actualy. Thx for your notice. Then `nunuspascal` way will help...